# How to build react app for production without making the website offline?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, npm

Is it possible to build react app for production using `npm run build` without it making the site offline? I am using nginx to serve the react app and when I run the above command, I get `Internal server` error until the build is finished. It would be nice if the old version of the app is served until the build is finished.

Comment: Where and how is the build result being served? You can probably do some kind of blue-green deployment, but the details will depend on your specific situation. If you build on the live server, then when it clears out the directory your site will go down (also if the build fails you've got a problem).

Comment: Are you building and deploying on Heroku?

Comment: Yes, I'm building on the live server (AWS E2) So I guess I should build locally and deploy to server as Mathew Daly said in his answer.

Comment: Ideally in a clean CI environment, with testing, so you can be confident that it works prior to deploying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be building your application on the production server. Build it locally, then deploy it to production and this won't be an issue.